# PowerShell Control Where CMD Window is Displayed

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

#### Problem

My PowerShell script generates a Form Window (with a fix startup location) and has a CMD Prompt window that is displayed alongside it that is used to display certain actions. However, with each successive launch of the PowerShell script, even though the Form Window stays in one place, the CMD Prompt window moves lower and lower as it makes its way systematically to the center of the screen. Once it reaches the center of the screen, it resets its position to the top left corner of the screen, only to repeat the process all over.

#### Question

Is it possible to designate the starting position of CMD Prompt Window, like you can with the Form window, so that I have more control over it?

Comment: Yes. See : https://www.windrath.com/2016/05/powershell-start-process-wrapper/

Comment: @SagePourpre : So you are basically saying "No, but there is a work around by using this partial code someone else wrote"? Not exactly what I was looking for... but it won't hurt to at least look through this

Comment: Well, there is no Powershell native way to do it. But this is as close as you get. You need to call the native SetWindowPos function from Windows API and  that code is a wrapper around that function which integrate the start-Process command and SetWindowPos in a function.

Comment: @SagePourpre : Well that is most unfortunate. At least there is a starting point to work with. Thank you